# AS3 for Facebook - why is my login callback not being called?

Tags: actionscript-3, facebook, facebook-graph-api

We're developing a Flash site that integrates with Facebook heavily.

We've noticed a bug where, if a user is not logged into Facebook, and we try to log them in via Facebook.login in the AS3 classes provided by Adobe, the callback is invoked, but the parameters result:Object and fail:Object are BOTH null. If our user then tries to login again, it all works fine, returning the userid in result:Object if successful.

Is this a bug with Facebook itself? Has anyone seen this before? We're sure this wasn't happening about a week ago.

```
Facebook.login(onLogin, {perms:Config.FB_PERMISSIONS});

private function onLogin(result:Object, fail:Object):void {

   // first time this is called after the popup closes returns
   // result == null and fail == null 
   // second time around, results are as expected
}
```

Cheers,
Mark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is kinda dirty, but for me a timeout before calling login worked fine:

setTimeout(Facebook.login, 200, onLogin, {perms:Config.FB_PERMISSIONS});

Comment: Yeah this is what we eventually did - or similar to it. I actually had to call Facebook.login twice to get it to work - I'd imagine a timeout would work as well.

Answer (score 4):

this is a way to connect to Facebook using Graph API. Everything is explained in comment. This is actually the connecting to facebook, no posting to walls or anything. That part can be found below this class.

```
package com.DAL 
{
    import com.facebook.graph.Facebook;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import com.facebook.graph.data.FacebookSession;
    import flash.events.EventDispatcher;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import com.fbLoginButton;
    import com.adobe.serialization.json.JSON;

    public class FBConnect extends EventDispatcher
    {
        /******************************************
        *   Variables
        ******************************************/
        private var _applicationID:String;
        private var _extendedPermissions:Object;

        /******************************************
        *   Constants
        ******************************************/
        public static const CONNECTED:String = "CONNECTED";

        /******************************************
        *   Properties
        ******************************************/             
        public function get applicationID():String
        {
            return _applicationID;
        }

        /******************************************
        *   Constructor
        ******************************************/
        public function FBConnect() 
        {
            super();

            //Set applicationid
            _applicationID = "YOUR_ID";

            //Set permissions to ask for
            _extendedPermissions = {perms:"read_stream, publish_stream, user_about_me, read_friendlists, user_photos"};

            //Initialize facebook
            Facebook.init(_applicationID);
        }

        /******************************************
        *   Methods
        ******************************************/     
        public function login(e:MouseEvent):void
        {           
            Facebook.login(handleLogin, _extendedPermissions);
        }

        private function handleLogin(response:Object, fail:Object):void
        {
            dispatchEvent(new Event(CONNECTED));
        }
    }
}
```

That should take care of connecting to facebook. If you want to post to walls or anything, you can find a small example below.

```
        /******************************************
        *   Constructor
        ******************************************/
        public function FBLogic() 
        {
            super();

            _connect = new FBConnect();
            _connect.addEventListener(FBConnect.CONNECTED, startLoaders);

            initLoaders();
        }

        /******************************************
        *   Methods
        ******************************************/

        ...

        public function post(message:String):void
        {
            var _params:Object = new Object();

            _params.access_token = Facebook.getSession().accessToken;
            _params.message = message;

            Facebook.api("/" + _userID + "/feed", messagePosted, _params, "POST");
        }

        public function messagePosted(response:Object, fail:Object):void
        {
            dispatchEvent(new Event(MESSAGEPOSTED));
        }

        public function login(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            var _loginButton:fbLoginButton = e.target as fbLoginButton;
            _loginButton.alpha = 0;
            _loginButton.visible = false;

            _connect.login(e);
        }
```

If this doesn't do the trick you might have forgotten to add some code to your html file. Be sure to add the following code to the head of your html file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
```

And you also need a div called fb-root, declared like this.

```
<body>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <div id="flashContent">
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Great. This worked for me and solution is nicely put together in a separate class. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 2):

> _extendedPermissions = {**perms**:"read_stream, publish_stream, user_about_me, read_friendlists, user_photos"};
>   Blockquote

"perms" is now "scope"

> {**scope**:"read_stream, publish_stream, user_about_me, read_friendlists, user_photos"};

This is not very well documented on the Adobe Facebook API page.

Answer (score 0):

SHORT ANSWER

Just keep Facebook.init() looping every 0.5 seconds until it finds a valid credential cookie.

LONG ANSWER

The docs describe Facebook.init() as a setup function. But it does more than that, it looks for valid fb logon cookie. As does Facebook.login().

The idea is call Facebook.init() at startup and see if user already have access. Else use Facebook.login() to make the user logon.

Not executable code:

```
    /**
    * Start the app, and see if there are any valid credentials
    **/
    public function startApp() {
        Facebook.init(fbAppid, handleFbLogin);
    }

    /** 
    * This is a method to call the app didnt login successfully
    * at startup.
    **/
    private function tryLogin() {
        Facebook.login(handleFbLogin, {});      
    }

    private var lastLoginSuccess:Object; //being a bit pedantic maybe

    /**
    * This is the callback that is <i>supposed</i> to run
    * ones the user has logged in.
    * Unfortunately the callback assoc. with the login/init  
    * goes off almost instantly; and so often fails before 
    * valid credentials have been creations >:(
    **/
    public function handleFbLogin(success:Object, fail:Object) {
        lastLoginSuccess = success;
        if(success){            
                    //yay!
        } else { 
                    //taps foot impatiently...
                flash.utils.setTimeout(tryFbInitIfLastFailed, 500);
        }
    }

    /**
    * And also the user could be taking their sweet time
    * typing in their password.
    * Oh and giving their device informative names like 'qwe'
    * 
    * So when they finally login, and the regularly executing
    * handleFbLogin() will finally find some valid credentials
    **/
    private function tryFbInitIfLastFailed() {              
        if (lastLoginSuccess == null)       
            Facebook.init(view.fbApp.id, handleFbLogin);    
    }
```

Any why not keep calling Facebook.login()? because the opens the Facebook login popup - so you will have a steady stream of popups.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, either if im not logged in or if im already:

```
        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
            Facebook.init("APPID", onInit);
        }

        private function onInit(response:Object, fail:Object):void
        {
            if(response)
            {
                handleLoginResponse(true, null);                    
            }
            else
            {
                Facebook.login(handleLoginResponse, { scope: "email, user_photos, publish_stream" } );
            }
        }

        private function handleLoginResponse(result:Object, fail:Object):void
        {
                if (result != null) {
                     // Logged in
                } else {
                     // Goodbye :(
                }            
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add https for all.js in the tag you use in the html file